# Report Builder 2.0 Create a dataset with Parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I cannot get my dataset to recognise a parameter supplied to it.
I have created a report parameter "ProjectID". 
(In Report Parameter Properties, `Name="ProjectID", Prompt="ProjectID"`).

In Dataset Properties|Parameters,  `Parameter Name="ID", Parameter Value="[@ProjectID]"`.

When I click on the Filter button in Query Designer, the "Projects with" panel says:
`"? ID equals (unspecified)"`.

But when I run the query I'm not prompted to enter a parameter value, and multiple rows are returned.

I should stress that I'm simply trying to replicate the functionality of a pre-existing report where all this works exactly as expected.

When I diff the rdl files of the two reports there are obvious differences, and I can hack the xml (of the semantic query) so that it works, but I don't really have the understanding of *why* it's working, or how to replicate the necessary changes via the GUI.

Can someone please give me some pointers - preferably without referring me to the documentation as I've been through this numerous times as well!!

Thanks in advance,
Peter.

p.s. I can post some of the rdl differences if that will help, but wanted to keep my initial post clear and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so what you need to do is when in the Filter screen of the Query designer, assuming you've already specified a filter in the main pane, such as:
"ID equals (unspecified)"

You need to click on "ID" and a context menu appears with "Edit as Formula", "Prompt" and "Remove Condition".

Select "Prompt", and there you go.